# Disabling color output in Vite – Equivalent to webpack-cli's `--no-color`?

Tags: webpack, vite

Is there a way to disable color output in Vite, similar to webpack-cli's `--no-color` option?

1. `--no-color` is not a valid parameter
2. I tried `FORCE_COLOR=0 vite` but I still see the colored output
3. Tried with `CI` env parameter but it didn't help either

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One of my more resourceful colleagues figured out that setting env

```
NO_COLOR=true
```

worked for us ( at least on windows, where the output was mucking up production logs).
Good luck.